# How would one get Google XML Pages to recognize and allow new HTML 5 elements?

Tags: xml-namespaces, gxp

[Google XML Pages](http://code.google.com/p/gxp/) say they support "standard html as long as it's formatted as xml" but they seem to only support html 4.0. The namespace used for supporting html is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and generating output from a gxp that contains elements like `<header>` `<nav>` or `<footer>` complains that the element is unknown in the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace.

Is there some different namespace I should be using or do gxps really only support HTML 4?

Here's a reference example gxp file where removing the wrapping `header` tag works just fine:

```
<gxp:template
  name='com.example.gxps.Test'
  xmlns:gxp='http://google.com/2001/gxp'
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <b>
        <gxp:msg>Hello,</gxp:msg>
        <br/>
        <gxp:msg>World!</gxp:msg>
      </b>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
</gxp:template>
```

As is though, it'll output something like:

> > java/com/example/gxps/Test.gxp:7:5:7:5: Unknown element `<header>` (in http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace)

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I figure would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GXP must have an (old) version of the Namespace definitions, built into it.

It appears that HTML5 and HTML4 use the same namespace, so there's no different namespace you need to use in your GXP pages. This is just an issue of updating/ adding the internal GXP definitions.

Download the source code & find where the definitions are! Ideally you can post/commit the updates back to the GXP project.

(I and other people are interested in GXP myself, so..  this would be really good work to do.)

Let me know how you go!